# Access: Names of Indices

Tags: database, ms-access, indexing

I have a Microsoft Access Database and I need to execute a statement :

**DROP INDEX Name ON Installations

However, Microsoft Access says that **no such index name found**. The column "Name" in the Installations table does have an index on it . I know this from the Access GUI . However, I can't use the ACCESS GUI to turn off the index (  I have to do the task by using the OleDbConnection class from a C# program - I'm writing a database upgrader ) .

Any ideas ? 
How do I get a list of of names of indices for a given table in Access ?

All the best,
Seb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I found it.

1. Open the table design.
2. Right click on the Title Bar
3. Select Indexes

[image: Index Name Example.png]

So in my example above, I would use:

```
drop index primarykey on bar
```

Answer (score 1):

VBScript suit?

```
Dim objEngine ''As DAO.DBEngine
Dim db ''As DAO.Database
Dim tdf ''As DAO.TableDef

strDAOversion = "DAO.DBEngine.36"
Set objEngine = WScript.CreateObject(strDAOversion)

Set db = objEngine.OpenDatabase("c:\Docs\db.mdb")
Set tdf = db.TableDefs("ATable")
For Each ndx In tdf.Indexes
    s = s & vbCrLf & ndx.Name
Next
MsgBox s
```